# "Can you please" vs. "Could you please"

Tags: word-usage

I heard using 'could' is for politeness. When I request something, should I say "Can you please" or "Could you please"? Does the latter sound over-polite and pretentious?

Answer (score 24):

If taken literally, "*Can you*" is equivalent to asking the person if they're capable of doing something.

"*Could you*", on the other hand, implies that the action can be completed under some circumstances by the person.

The usage of *can you* is idiomatic, and hence, is more popular used phrase of the two. Using either of them doesn't make them sound "over-polite". It's just that using *could you* is unusual with the modern day languages.

---

And example referring to difference between *can you* and *could you*.

I might first ask *can you please bring me X?* to find if he is capable to bring it. If the reply is a negation, I'll add *could you bring me X if Y?*; where `Y` is some kind of helping factor.

Comment: I disagree. I'd say they are for the most part equivalent.  "*Can you* walk with me to my car" or, "*Could you* walk with me to my car" - equivalent. To make the distinction you are attributing to "Could", I'd use the word "Would", or perhaps/sometimes "Will". I was going to say that generally, the more difficult or involved or complicated a task is, the more skill or physical strength is required for a  task, the more  "Can" and "Could" might diverge. But then I thought of "Can/Could you climb Mount Everest" - equivalent.